# Alternative for deprecated WorkQueueProcessor

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, flux, reactor

In recent reactor version [WorkQueueProcessor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/extra/processor/WorkQueueProcessor.html) got deprecated and set to be removed at version 3.5.
With the new Sinks spec, I'm wondering is there an alternative for WorkQueueProcessor? I'm looking to distribute the signals to only one of the subscribed subscribers, in a round-robin maner.

Comment: "deprecated" not depreciated.